# Trying to remove TabBarController Item but TabBar Controller is returning nil

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am passing data from a collection view cell when I push to a tab bar controller.

I have a Navigation Controller which I push a segue to a tabbarcontroller. So the TabBarController is in a navigation controller.

The data pass works excellent with this code which is in my prepare to segue.

```
let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let row = indexPath.row
        let tabar = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultsDetailViewController
        tabar.photoData = photoDataStore[row]
```

I subclass the TabBarController with a variable of photoData.  So all child view controllers work excellent.

But what I am trying to do is if photo2 is nil, then remove the 3rd view controller of the tabbarcontroller.  I got this code from another post.  Issue is self.tabbarcontroller is returning nil.  Can't figure out why?

```
    if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
        let indexToRemove = 2
        if indexToRemove < tabBarController.viewControllers?.count {
            var viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
            viewControllers?.removeAtIndex(indexToRemove)
            tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
        }
    }
```

As the tabbarcontroller was developed through storyboard I did not set it up in appdelegate.

In the end I want the number of tabbar buttons and hence the number of view controllers to be dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: How you are setting up your tabor controller in storyboard, please add a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok found the problem... with the custom Tabbarcontroller when I was doing self.tabbarcontroller which was returning nil... self is already the tabbarcontroller... so instead i just used self.viewcontrollers working code below.

```
        if var tabBarController = self.viewControllers {
            let indexToRemove = 2
            if indexToRemove < tabBarController.count {
                tabBarController.removeAtIndex(indexToRemove)
                self.setViewControllers(tabBarController, animated: false)
            }
        }
```

Comment: your observation helped-me. Thanks!